# Gridview databind based on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following in my page.

- 2 Asp Buttons
- 1 GridView
- 1 image button for export to excel

I need to view gridview based on respective buttons. i.e. Each button will have different data to displayed. Also gridview should allow paging as there are many records. Export to excel should also happen when image button is clicked including all pages in gridview. Can any one help in this ?

My code is following

aspx file.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div>
     <table id="Table2" width="100%" align="left" runat="server">
      <tr>
        <td class="auto-style8">
        </td>
         <td class="auto-style9"></td><td class="auto-style10">
             <asp:Button ID="Admin" runat="server" Text="Admin" TOOLTIP="Sign In" TABINDEX="3"  BackColor="Gray" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Groove" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="White" Height="46px" Width="85px"/>
                <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" StaticSubMenuIndent="" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Home" Value="Home" NavigateUrl="Admin_Main.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Add Customer" Value="Add Customer" NavigateUrl="Add_Details.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Delete Customer" Value="Delete Customer" NavigateUrl="Delete_Customer.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>

                </Items>

             </asp:Menu>   
             <asp:LinkButton ID="logout" runat="server" OnClick="logout_click" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large">Logout</asp:LinkButton>
         </td>
          </tr>
          </table>
          </div>
          <div>
     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="UserName" Font-Bold="True" 
                  Font-Size="X-Large"></asp:Label>
     <asp:TextBox ID="userName" Name= "userName"  runat="server" Font-Bold="True"></asp:TextBox>

     </div>
     <div>
      <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Email Log" OnClick= "Email_Click" Height="35px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Width="90px"/>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="All Log" Height="35px" OnClick= "Log_Click" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Width="90px"/>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnexport" runat="server" Height="35px" ImageUrl="~/Images/exp-xls.gif" Width="112px" OnClick="btnExport_Click" Visible="false" />
     </div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>

</asp:Content>
```

aspx.cs file

```
public partial class Display_Log : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string user = (string)(Session["user"]);
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (user == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/InvalidLogin.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Admin.Text = user;
                Admin.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
    protected void Email_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnn"].ConnectionString;
        cnn.ConnectionString = connStr;
        cnn.Open();
        String sqlSelect = String.Format(" Select Customer_Name,Time_Send_Clicked,Reminder_Type from Email_Log where Username='{0}'",userName.Text.ToString().Trim());
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, cnn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        cnn.Close();
        btnexport.Visible = true;



    }
    protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=ActivityReport_" + userName.Text + ".xls"));
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
          GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
    }

    protected void Log_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnn"].ConnectionString;
        cnn.ConnectionString = connStr;
        cnn.Open();
        String sqlSelect = String.Format(" SELECT [Activity],[Time],[Ticket_Number] FROM Log where Username='{0}'", userName.Text.ToString().Trim());
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, cnn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        cnn.Close();
        btnexport.Visible = true;
    }
    protected void logout_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Session["user"] = null;
        this.Session["group"] = null;
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: so the `btnExport_Click` only print the shown records and you want to export all the records when clicks? the binding looks fine

Comment: @Tarun Yes your right i need to export all records. Also i need to add paging in gridview.

Answer (score 0):

To add pagging u need to specify `AllowPaging="True"` this will add pagging but it wont work until u specify  this which handle the onclick event when page button is clicked
    `onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"`

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="Identityrowoftable" AllowPaging="True" 
onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" />
```

in code behind add this

```
 protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        // you need to rebind gridview here 
        //just set the source and databind
    }
```

after this the print part

first you need to clear controls so unwanted elements dont come while print.

```
private void ClearControls(Control control)
    {
        for (int i = control.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            ClearControls(control.Controls[i]);
        }

        if (!(control is TableCell))
        {
            if (control.GetType().GetProperty("SelectedItem") != null)
            {
                LiteralControl literal = new LiteralControl();
                control.Parent.Controls.Add(literal);
                try
                {
                    literal.Text =
                        (string)control.GetType().GetProperty("SelectedItem").
                            GetValue(control, null);
                }
                catch
                { }
                control.Parent.Controls.Remove(control);
            }
            else if (control.GetType().GetProperty("Text") != null)
            {
                LiteralControl literal = new LiteralControl();
                control.Parent.Controls.Add(literal);
                literal.Text =
                    (string)control.GetType().GetProperty("Text").
                        GetValue(control, null);
                control.Parent.Controls.Remove(control);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

how to use ClearControl when exporting as excel

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Reference your own GridView here
        if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 65535)
        {
            //DisplayError("Export to Excel is not allowed" +
            //    "due to excessive number of rows.");
            return;
        }

        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=nameofexcelfile_" + DateTime.Now+".xls" );
        Response.Charset = "";

        // SetCacheability doesn't seem to make a difference (see update)
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);

        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

        System.IO.StringWriter stringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

        // Replace all gridview controls with literals

        GridView1.PagerSettings.Visible = false;
        ClearControls(GridView1);

        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form
            = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm();
        Controls.Add(form);
        form.Controls.Add(GridView1GridView1);
        form.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
        Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

**this will print records without paging buttons**